# Best practices for using background-size with absolute values

Tags: html, css

For years we've lived without `background-size` property, but now [it is supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) practically by the overwhelming majority of browsers.

There are at least two cases when `background-size` is a very handy property:

1. Resizing background relatively to the size of some container.
2. Resizing background for creating animation effects.

But what about absolutely sizing backgrounds for static (in sense, without invoking any kind of animations effects) content? We always can just resize images we need to resize without invoking `background-size` property. So, since this is relatively new property and I have no feeling how to use it right, my question is: Talking exceptionally about absolute values, when I should and when I shouldn't use background-size instead of image preprocessing?

**UPD:** here is a [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/wE6M5/1/) to make my question clearer.

Comment: What do you mean, resizing for static content?

Comment: @Brad I mean that as for content with some animations it is obvious how background-sizing is useful. I've edited the question to make it clearer. Indeed, "static" has a lot of meanings.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking.  Can you provide a concrete example?

Comment: sure, just give me a couple of minutes to provide a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are almost none use-cases that use exceptionally absolute values — I can think only of using client-side-only solutions when you just don't have any sever-side power to process images.

So, the answer for you strict question would be “there are none”, so I'd better answer the more wide question :)

1. When using with CSS gradients you could either emulate repeating-gradients, either make [patterns](http://24ways.org/2011/css3-patterns-explained/) with it, either use it for better performance. The last case is the most interesting: when you have some gradient set on an element, it would be rendered at this element's height and width, and that could be resource consuming sometimes. In a lot of cases you could limit the size of the gradient either by one dimension or, sometimes, by both, so browser would render it at, say, 100x100 and not at 1280x9001.
2. Using `background-size: cover` to make sure the image is filling the block. For example, you app could have userpics or thumbnails, and most of them would be of one specific size, like 50x50. However, there'd be ones that are smaller or bigger than that, and `background-size` would be perfect here — you could use the `cover` here to make this image fit the area (well, that's not with absolute values, but it is really handy, often with `background-position: 50% 0` to make heads to be shown withou trimming in case of portrait photoes for usepics). And another similar case — making [full page backgrounds](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) with background-size.
3. Background-size could often be used for making images for retina-like displays, so the images would either be always shrinked (and be that way even on non-retina displays), or be conditionally shrinked (using mediaqueries for dpi).
4. When you have some image galleries, you often would have some thumbnails that then would become full images on click. You could achieve a nice effect similar to progressive jpegs if you'd place the resized thumbnails as the background for the full size images as `<img/>` tags — that way while the big images are loading you would have a blurred image as a placeholder. It's even better when used in lightbox-like thigies with popups.

Ah, and while you told not to mention animations, I just can't control mysel, so I'm placing a link to [this demo](http://lab.simurai.com/space-cacss/) here :)